# iTunes Connect: app’s developer support website

Tags: app-store-connect

It used to be one can update developer’s support website for an existing app.  I can’t seem to find it anywhere.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how to use a web site, not about programming.

Comment: Agreed not a programming question.  But the iTunesConnect tag ... please close this if needed be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the current version of the app (probably says "Ready For Sale") to show its details page. The Support URL field you're looking for is about 1/4 of the way down, on the right. Make a change and hit the Save button at the top.

Comment: Although the answer is very useful for the OP, I suggest [not answering off-topic question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions).